# Display week number column in calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create on full calendar in jquery.

1) The first column is week and respectively sun,mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat.

2) Week column need to display the week.

Please look at the below image,

[image]

I want to do this in a jquery. I don't want to use any other plugins like fullCalendar and all. I want to use only jquery plugin.

Comment: what problems did you encounter? drop some code here

Comment: this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474557/show-week-number-in-fullcalendar

Comment: what you tried..share your code.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution.

Html :

```
<div class="wrapper">
<form class="ws-validate">  
  <div class="form-row show-selectnav show-week hide-btnrow">  
        <input id="date-4" type="date" data-date='{"minView": 2, "startView": 2}' />
    </div>
  </form>
```

Javascript :

```
<div class="wrapper">
<form class="ws-validate">  
  <div class="form-row show-selectnav show-week hide-btnrow">  
        <input id="date-4" type="date" data-date='{"minView": 2, "startView": 2}' />
    </div>
  </form>
```

You can see working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Deep7/VNuct/673/).
Hope will work for you..☺

Comment: Thank you so much. This is correct. But I want to display that calendar like a table. Please look at this fiddle [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/100thgear/h9cc6/)

Comment: @sathishkumar didn't you said in question that you don't want to use FullCalendar yet in this fiddle it is FullCalendar?

Comment: yes. This is what I am asking. I want to do the same thing in jquery, what it is there in fullCalendar

Comment: @sathishkumar I don't know for what you need it but here is quick workaround with solution from this answer https://jsfiddle.net/VNuct/674/ so now input is hidden and calendar is displayed by default

Comment: Sorry @jakob. I have 2 calendars, If I select startdate(29/06/2016) and enddate(10/10/2016), I want to display this dates in full calendar view in a container as per the selected date range.

Comment: U have used polyfiller.js file. I don't want to use any plugin. I want to do in jquery itself.

Comment: well if you want all this options without existing plugin you will have to code new one in jquery for yourself.. it's not easy or fast thing to do

Comment: still u have any problem in this code then tell me, I will update it & repost u..☺ @sathishkumar