# How to add week column in full Calendar plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I am trying to using fullCalendar plugin in my project. Please look at the following fiddle,

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/100thgear/h9cc6/)

Here, calendar will start at sun, mon,tue,wed,thur,fri and sat.

1) I want to add one more column before sunday. The first column is week. It should display the current week of the year. (i.e ) If the current week is 27 (july 4th to 10th ) means, it should display the 27 in the week column. Same as for all weeks.

2) How to add the week column in full calendar plugin.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var events_array = [
        {
        title: 'Test1',
        start: new Date(2012, 8, 20),
        tip: 'Personal tip 1'},
    {
        title: 'Test2',
        start: new Date(2012, 8, 21),
        tip: 'Personal tip 2'}
    ];

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        events: events_array,
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.attr('title', event.tip);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div style="border:solid 2px red;">
        <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain it properly what you want

Comment: Please see the fiddle. Totally 7 columns are there sunday to saturday. I want to add one more column "Week". This is the first column and It should display the particular week. For example today date is july 7th, and this is 27th week in a year. I want to display 27 in the column of week. If I select any date in next week, I want to display 28 in a next week column. Like that I want.

Comment: I may help you but it will take much time

Comment: weekNumbers: true,

Comment: Refer this link I think Its what you forget to do [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474557/show-week-number-in-fullcalendar)

Comment: yeah correct.Thank you so much,.

Comment: then you should accept my answer

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var events_array = [
        {
        title: 'Test1',
        start: new Date(2012, 8, 20),
        tip: 'Personal tip 1'},
    {
        title: 'Test2',
        start: new Date(2012, 8, 21),
        tip: 'Personal tip 2'}
    ];

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        weekNumbers:true,
        events: events_array,
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.attr('title', event.tip);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div style="border:solid 2px red;">
        <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: goto link and download fullcalender.js